# Is there a way to install Laravel Jetstream in Laravel 8.6 without downgrading PHP version?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-jetstream

I am trying to install Laravel Jetstream in `Laravel 8.6` but keep getting a PHP version error.
Unfortunately I need `Laravel 8.6` to test for a bug that's in a deployment server.

These are the steps I have followed so far

1. Install laravel
   `composer create-project laravel/laravel test 8.6.8`
2. Try to install jetstream
   `composer require laravel/jetstream`
   `php artisan jetstream:install inertia`

This gives me the error
Problem 1

> Root composer.json requires inertiajs/inertia-laravel ^0.5.2 ->
> satisfiable by inertiajs/inertia-laravel[v0.5.2, v0.5.3, v0.5.4].

> inertiajs/inertia-laravel[v0.5.2, ..., v0.5.4] require php
> ^7.2|~8.0.0|~8.1.0 -> your php version (8.2.6) does not satisfy that
> requirement.

Does anyone anyone know of a solution that doesn't require a PHP downgrade?

Comment: You still need to make a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example meaning at least showing relevant parts of your composer.json. inertia, starting from v0.6.4 cab handle PHP 8.2, but it also requires Laravel ^8.74 (so not Laravel 8.6). Just try to update those versions and then show results and composer.json

Comment: If this package is not satisfied by the php version what you have you have one choice to fork this package and make sure that this forked package meet 8.2 requirements.

Comment: It looks like inertiajs requires Laravel version 8.74+ specifically. It's odd but there must be a reason. You should upgrade your laravel minor version. Since Laravel uses semantic versioning you should be able to do this without any other code changes

Comment: The jetstream version you are trying to install depends on inertia/inertia-laravel version 0.5.2 or higher, which requires PHP version 7.2 or higher. It doesn't satisfy the requirement since you are using PHP version 8.2.6.

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/laravel/jetstream/issues/200